# Cannot access data in JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying the access the json response from the server, using the following code. According to firebug, my server is outputting what looks like a valid json response as follows:

```
{"result":"error","message":"This group is not empty"}
```

my JavaScript is as below, but when I try to alert() the data from json response, I get nothing

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: data_ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'data_mysql_record_id=' + data_mysql_record_id + '&data_mysql_table_name=' + data_mysql_table_name,

        //success, annimate and remove row
        success: function(data){

           alert(data.result);
            //get a json message from server if one exists
            $ajax_response = data.message;
            if ($ajax_response == '' || $ajax_response == 'undefined') {
                $ajax_response = 'Request has been completed';
            }
            //slide up table row
            parent.slideUp(300, function(){
                parent.remove();
            });

            //show noty notification 1 sec later
            setTimeout(function(){
                noty({
                    text: $ajax_response,
                    layout: 'bottomRight',
                    type: 'information',
                    timeout: 1300
                });
            }, 1000);
        },

        //error - alert
        error: function(data){

            alert(data.result); //my test

            //get a json message from server if one exists
            $ajax_response = data.message; //where 'message' is key in php jason output
            if ($ajax_response == '' || $ajax_response == 'undefined') {
                $ajax_response = 'Error!- This request could not be completed';
            }

            //fire up a noty message
            noty({
                text: ''+$ajax_response,
                layout: 'bottomRight',
                type: 'warning',
                timeout: 1300
            });

        }
```

### UPDATE:

```
            //data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
```

Console.log is giving me this

```
readyState
    4

responseJSON
    Object { result="error", message="This group is not empty"}

responseText
    "{"result":"error","mess...is group is not empty"}"

status
    400

statusText
    "Bad Request"
```

and

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
```

is giving this error

```
            SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character   
            ...nction(e){var t,n="",r=0,i=e.nodeType;if(i){if(1===i||9===i||11===i)                {if("string"...
```

The status 400 and "bad request" is something I am oputiing in my php headers to show that there was an error backend

Comment: What does alert(data) give you?

Comment: If I alert(data); before parsing it with jQuery.parseJSON(data)...I am getting output of 'object Object' is this correct? is data not just a string prior to parsing it with jQuery.parseJSON(data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` handler of an [`$.ajax` request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has the signature

> `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`
>
> […] *receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.*

Change your function to

```
error: function(jqXhr) {
    var data = jqXhr.responseJSON; // you saw this in your console.log
    if (data) {
        …
    } else {
        // there might be other errors, where you don't get the server message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with parsing the JSON data in the javascript :

Before using the json data

```
data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(data.result);
```

Try this.

Comment: when I try this, I am getting this error in my browser console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character .....however when I test the json output at jsonlint.com its validating ok –

Comment: If you are getting the your response like `"{"result":"error","mess...is group is not empty"}"` then check your json again because I checked it in the jsonlint.com and its invalid. Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/HeFYn/).

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery.parseJSON and might I suggest to use console.log instead of alert, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: data_ajax_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'data_mysql_record_id=' + data_mysql_record_id + '&data_mysql_table_name=' + data_mysql_table_name,

    //success, annimate and remove row
    success: function(data){

       data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       console.log(data.result);

        //get a json message from server if one exists

        $ajax_response = data.message;
        if ($ajax_response == '' || $ajax_response == 'undefined') {
            $ajax_response = 'Request has been completed';
        }

        //slide up table row
        parent.slideUp(300, function(){
            parent.remove();
        });

        //show noty notification 1 sec later
        setTimeout(function(){
            noty({
                text: $ajax_response,
                layout: 'bottomRight',
                type: 'information',
                timeout: 1300
            });
        }, 1000);
    },

    //error - alert
    error: function(data){

        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(data); //my test

        //get a json message from server if one exists
        $ajax_response = data.message; //where 'message' is key in php jason output
        if ($ajax_response == '' || $ajax_response == 'undefined') {
            $ajax_response = 'Error!- This request could not be completed';
        }

        //fire up a noty message
        noty({
            text: ''+$ajax_response,
            layout: 'bottomRight',
            type: 'warning',
            timeout: 1300
        });

    }
```

Comment: when I try this, I am getting this error in my browser console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character .....however when I test the json output at http://jsonlint.com/ its validating ok

Comment: If I alert(data); before parsing it with jQuery.parseJSON(data)...I am getting output of 'object Object' is this correct? is data not just a string prior to parsing it with jQuery.parseJSON(data)?

Comment: You should use console.log instead of alert, it is more detailed.

Comment: I would like to see your json, as otherwise I cannot determine what the problem is. Please, console.log it out and tell me what the result is. If you have secrets there, then feel free to change them, as I am only interested in the technical situation to be able to help..

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON('{"result":"error","message":"This group is not empty"}') successfully parses the JSON. Now, I believe you already have a JSON there, as the result is not inside apostrophes.